# Vim - Delete blank line using backspace in insert mode

Tags: vim

When my cursor is placed at the start of an empty line and I press the backspace key while in insert mode, I'd expect it to wrap the the previous line. However it stays in the same line and does nothing.

I can't seem to figure out what I should add to my .vimrc file to fix this.

[image]

Comment: See [Why doesn't the backspace key work in insert mode?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2162)

Answer (score 14):

You can set `backspace` option:

```
:set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

Or

```
:set bs=2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you manually install `Vim`, no matter where you are on `Debian`, or

`Ubuntu`, or even other platform, please add the below code to your

`~/.vimrc`(The below code works on my Debian manually installed Vim):

```
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

After `set nocompatible " be iMproved, required` under `~/.vimrc`.

Notice: `set backspace=2` Do Not Work on my Debian manually installed Vim.

My `Debian` Manually installed `Vim` version is: `8.2`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance working from a windows system? using putty for example?

Sometimes I've seen terminal emulators on windows mess up backspace, so it "sorta" works. 
Eg. in putty, there a setting under "terminal -> keyboard" for changing how backspace works. Try that.